# Can't get expanded url from shortened url in java

Tags: java, httpconnection, bit.ly

I have the following code which expands the shortened url.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.URL;
public class ExpandUrl {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String shortenedUrl = "2q3GMg0"; //read note at the bottom. 
        String expandedURL = ExpandUrl.expand(shortenedUrl);
        System.out.println("expanded url is :  " + expandedURL); 
    }

    public static String expand(String shortenedUrl) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(shortenedUrl);    
        // open connection
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(Proxy.NO_PROXY); 

      int status = 0;
      try {
          status = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

      System.out.println("status is " + status);

        // stop following browser redirect
        httpURLConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);

        // extract location header containing the actual destination URL
        String expandedURL = httpURLConnection.getHeaderField("Location");
        httpURLConnection.disconnect();

        return expandedURL;
    }
}
```

The code expands some of the urls but returns null for some other urls. 
e.g: it expands `2q3GMg0`  but returns null when I use `9mglq8` although the status code is 200 for this. I have tested both url. Both are valid and has expanded form.

**Note:** Stackoverflow didn't allow me to put shortened link in body so I have just mentioned the hashcode.

**Edit:** Links for which I am getting null doesn't have a `Location` header field. In such case how do I retrieve the original expanded link?

```
status is 200
Key: null  value: [HTTP/1.1 200 OK]
Key: X-Cache  value: [Hit from cloudfront]
Key: Server  value: [Apache]
Key: Connection  value: [keep-alive]
Key: Last-Modified  value: [Sat, 12 May 2018 12:06:48 GMT]
Key: Date  value: [Sat, 12 May 2018 12:11:30 GMT]
Key: Via  value: [1.1 587a74dd892ff33ecf276aa569c8b68a.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)]
Key: X-Frame-Options  value: [SAMEORIGIN]
Key: Accept-Ranges  value: [bytes]
Key: Cache-Control  value: [max-age=120, s-maxage=120, public]
Key: X-Amz-Cf-Id  value: [-p1_VjHmvcGCI1PbQelSHpUectu_5NfCFUnPu_NUHCJ9_2lS2rTmlA==]
Key: Vary  value: [Accept-Encoding]
Key: X-XSS-Protection  value: [1]
Key: Content-Length  value: [186539]
Key: Age  value: [108]
Key: Content-Type  value: [text/html]
```

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using `java.net.URL` ? Because I'm receiving a `MalformedURLException`

Comment: I have edited the code. check it.

Comment: What are all the headers you receive inside the `httpURLConnection` object when the `expandedURL` variable contains `null`? Please add the full response header from the request in your question from the URL which failed.

Comment: Post couple of shortened links/URLs(working and non-working) as an image.

Comment: @YassinHajaj You might have tried the code as is. Note the note in OP.

Comment: @YassinHajaj Share URL with which you tried.

Comment: @YassinHajaj Which is what I did as 4th comment. I asked specifically you, as you had mentioned(1st comment) that you get `MalformedURLException`.

Comment: @MONUKUMAR Can you share shortened links for which value is returned as null? Add it as an image in OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the status code is `200` there is no redirection and there will be no `Location` field in the header and hence null is returned when you try to access the value of `Location` key. you can get the expanded URL using `httpURLConnection.getURL()`.

If the status code is `301` or `302` there is a redirection and there will be a `Location` field in the header. You can get the redirected URL as:

`String expandedURL = httpURLConnection.getHeaderField("Location");`

like you have done.

hope this helps.

Comment: @MONU KUMAR Your statement in OP - "... but returns null when I use 9mglq8 although the status code is 200 for this." contradicts with selected answer. Check [HTTP status code](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) definitions at w3.org site.

Comment: @Explorer, I know that but I had in my mind that if the request has succeeded, it should give me the expanded URL. I was wrong. From status code 200 you can deduce that there is no redirerction. Thanks for pointing btw.

Answer (score -1):

Probably, the proxy is blocking.

**EDIT:** Whoever down-voted this: I tried with both bit.ly URLs and both of them work fine.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. If you're sure it's the proxy blocking, then edit your answer and post a full-explained answer.